# How do I make the data passed in a table is no longer displayed in the other

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

I have a problem for a couple of hours does not resolve, is the following.

I have a Table A and Table B.

Table A is filled with a ResultSet, and Table B is being added to products available in Table A

What I am trying to achieve is: Once you click on the Add button Spend the product of Table A to Table B, and the last product is no longer displayed in Table A.

Answer (score 2):

The responsibility to inform the tables that data was added and remove to and from them is completely up to you, and should be handled in each table's model.  If you want to 'move' data from one to the other, you need to remove that data from the model of the first table and add it to the 2nd.  Once that is done, both models need to be informed of the change via fireTableDataChanged, so they know to redraw.

Answer (score 1):

I would endorse @Colby's and @GETah's suggestion to focus on the model. Also consider giving `modelA` and `modelB` access to a common data structure, say `List<Product>`, where each `Product` has a boolean attribute that allows each model to to decide what it's corresponding view can see.

Comment: that's interesting, imaging that +1

Answer (score 0):

Get and remove the selected element from `tableA`'s `TableModel` and add it to the `tableB`'s `TableModel` and then refresh both tables.
See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) on using `JTable` and `TableModel`

Comment: -1 for "then refresh both tables" - no need to do anything else except manipulating the tableModels, provided they are well-behaved

Comment: @kleopatra Nope, you need to fire an event to the top layers to refresh your views otherwise changes won't show on the UI

Comment: no, not if the tableModels are implemented correctly - the add/remove _must_ fire themselves

Comment: @kleopatra **How do you know if the models are implemented correctly?** A TableModel should fire events when the underlying data model has changed, this in turn will notify the JTable that a change has occurred and it should be redrawn. Yes add/remove must fire themselves if AbstractTableModel is implemented or correctly **implemented** in case the model is defined from scratch

Comment: can't know of course - but if they aren't that's the thingy to do: correct its implementation, instead of "refresh" whatever manually. That's the point I intended to emphasize :-)